# Cannot unregister Debian in WSL

Tags: installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, uninstall

I've just formatted my PC and tried to reinstall my Debian distro.

Before formatting, I ran `wsl --export` to get a TAR file for Debian. After installing Windows again, I enabled WSL in the Option Features GUI, rebooted, and then ran `wsl --import`.

Now, it seems like the imported distro isn't properly recognised.

```
PS C:\Users\username> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Debain                 Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
PS C:\Users\username> wsl --unregister debian
Unregistering.
There is no distribution with the supplied name.
Error code: Wsl/Service/WSL_E_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND
PS C:\Users\username> wsl --unregister Debian
Unregistering.
There is no distribution with the supplied name.
Error code: Wsl/Service/WSL_E_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND
PS C:\Users\username> wsl
Failed to attach disk 'E:\vm\wsl\debian\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the path specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
```

I've tried rebooting Windows in between too. I've also tried just unchecking the WSL box in Optional Features, rebooting Windows, rechecking it, and then rebooting Windows again. Nothing helps.

System info (ThinkPad E14, Gen 4):

```
Device name [REDACTED]
Processor   12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1260P   2.10 GHz
Installed RAM   24.0 GB (23.7 GB usable)
Device ID   [REDACTED]
Product ID  [REDACTED]
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎12/‎02/‎2023
OS build    22621.1105
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22638.1000.0
```

Comment: Uhm because your WSL name is "Debain"?

Comment: @TomYan: He tried both names.

Comment: @eccentricOrange: Try running PowerShell as Administrator. If it still happens, try using a Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator.

Comment: @harrymc No, he tried Debian and debian, not "Debain"

Comment: @harrymc admin PS and admin CMD don't work either.

Comment: @TomYan No permutation of uppercase, lowercase, and with/without quotes works. Same error.

Comment: @eccentricOrange I was talking about misspelling.

Comment: @TomYan: Good eyes - the distribution name is indeed misspelled to **Debain**. This is probably the reason for the problem.

Comment: @TomYan I want to downvote my question now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While (from the comments) the problem in this case turned out to be a misspelling of "Debian" (as "Debain") when using `wsl --import`, I'm going to point out that this was a *good* accident.

In general, I recommend *not* using `wsl --import` with a WSL distribution named `Debian`, or any "stock" name that might be used by an existing distribution that can be installed from the Store (i.e. "ubuntu", "ubuntu-22.04", "Kali-Linux", "Alpine", etc.).

The "Debian"-named distribution should be reserved for the one actually created by the Debian installer (which is based on a common [WSL-distro-launcher](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher) reference implementation).  This distribution has a few key differences from an `--import`ed distro:

- There are additional registry keys which are automatically generated by the installer.
- The installer (and uninstaller, in previous releases) fixes the location of the distribution in the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<PackageName>` directory.
- The installer application creates some additional metadata in that package folder.

While the reference distro-launcher *may* handle the corner case of a "distro-launcher-distro" being where it isn't "expected" to be, I believe it's safer to use a different distro name when `wsl --import`ing.

For instance, I preface my user-distros with `ntd_` (for NotTheDr01ds), so my "working" Ubuntu is called:

```
ntd_Ubuntu_22.04_WSL2
```

This also means that I can spin up a temporary "distro-launcher" version of Ubuntu 22.04 simply by running:

```
ubuntu2204.exe
```

I can use it as a test for some new software or configuration, then I can "throw it away" when done with `wsl --unregister ...`.